# How to convert encode in R

Tags: r

Here is the some convertion in python,locale is "utf-8"

```
>>> s1="你好"   #你好 = how are you?
>>> s2=unicode(s1,"utf-8")
>>> s2
u'\u4f60\u597d'                #s2  is the unicode form of s1
>>> s3=s2.encode("utf-8")
>>> s3
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'     #s3  is the utf-8 form of s1
>>> s4=s2.encode("gbk")
>>> s4 
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'              #s3  is the gbk  form of s1
```

How can i do it in R?

Comment: > iconv(s1,from="utf-8",to="unicode")，i get the output ,but i think it 's wrong.
[1] "\xff\xfe`O}Y",it is not the same as what i get with python.
> iconv(s1,from="utf-8",to="gbk")
[1] "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3"
how can i get unicode of "你好"  in  R?

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions that help you to convert from `utf-8` to `hexmode`:

- `utf8ToInt`
- `as.hexmode`

Try this:

```
as.hexmode(utf8ToInt(s1))
[1] "4f60" "597d"
```

---

But as for the `gbk` conversion, I'm sorry I haven't a clue.